# Why use detrending methods when studying seasonality of a phenomenon?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, moving-average

I have a basic question, I am trying to study the seasonality of birth in a town, and all the material I am researching use moving average for detrending and these values are eventually used for  linear regression to study the effect of certain conditions that may/maynot affect the seasonality.
I am trying to understand why detrending is used, it takes out the trends but it is the trends(seasonality) that I want to understand. I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the theory behind it.

Answer (score 0):

first make the time series decomposition, you will have seasonal cycle, trend component and residualds. if you have other exegenous variables to identify rest of the variation (error) than use residuals as dependent variable.